# Is there a DRY way to do this in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dry

I have a method which is taking optional arguments. And in the method I am doing query on the optional arguments like this:

```
    def filter_element(param1, *param2)
      param2[0].empty? ? filtered_element = Model_class.where('city = ?',   param1) : filtered_element = Model_class.where('city = ? and price <= ?', param1, param2[0].to_i)
    end
```

This is an example with one optional arguments passed into the method.

My question is, if i have more than one optional arguments and want to use it in the query arguments depending on its presence, how can I do that?

I know i can use if, elsif etc. But I want to use a DRY way to do it.

I am pretty sure there is a way, but couldn't find anything related to it.

Comment: A method with one optional argument usually looks like this: `def filter_element(param1, param2 = nil)`. Furthermore, the local variables `filtered_element` and `filtered_advertiesments` are never used.

Comment: I updated the code. This method returns filtered_element. As far I understand, Its not a good practice to pass nil in the query, hence there is no nil as default value.

Comment: You don't have to assign the return value to a variable at all, i.e. remove both `filtered_element = ` and just write `... ? Model_class.where(...) : Model_class.where(...)`

Comment: yes, i know that. My question was related to having multiple optional parameters in the query itself. The answer from Kostev was what I was looking for. Thanks for your input though. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be done differently

```
#it's better to pass arguments not like array, but as hash
def filter_element(city, options = {})
  scope = Model_class.where(city:  city)
  scope = scope.where('price <= ?', options[:price].to_i) if options[:price].present?
  #some more scope limitation here

  scope
end

element = filter_element('Minsk', price: 500)
```

Comment: With your code, `options` is a hash inside an array which will result in an exception. Just get rid of the asterisk and things will be fine. Or even better, use `def filter_element(city, options={})` to have an actual optional parameter.

Comment: Or use [keyword arguments](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Keyword+Arguments), i.e. `def filter_element(city, price: nil)`

Comment: Okay, let me try this. Thanks

Comment: @tanvir2362 my code will handle you requirements. If param1 present it will build one where condition, if price is present it will build two where statements. Then activerecord will do the rest. It will build 1 sql statement with and between conditions

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. I need to think more of a ruby way.

Comment: @kostev And I am still using the *array, in the optional parameter. My concern was to do it DRY way. You sent me to the right direction. :)